# Where does my picture go?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm creating an app that allows the user to take a picture. I'm using the code bit below and then load the image into an UIImageVIew to display on screen. No problems, but once I've taken the image, where does it go? If I don't actually save the image to my camera roll, where is it? Is it held in memory until I close my app?

Can I save is somehow with NSUserDefaults?

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {


    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;


    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: It goes nowhere except in the `UIImage` object you get in the delegate callback.

Comment: So it stays in memory until the application quits ?

Comment: Only if you keep a reference to the `UIImage`. As soon as you no longer have the reference, it will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

using something like this `UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; self.myImage = chosenImage;`  will store your image in your app and you can call on it again later